# Problem with first and last element in list being manipulated twice

Tags: python, list, append

```
List = []
while True:
   filename = input("Enter input file name: ")
   try:
      infile = open(filename, "r")
      break
   except FileNotFoundError:
      print("File not found, please try again")
List = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in infile]
List = [i.split(",") for i in List]
List = [[int(num) for num in lstt[:]] for lstt in List]
if List[-1] != List[0]:
List.append(List[0])
print(List)
```

So my code basically reads in a txt file and then converts the coordinates in the file to a list of lists, such as:

```
List = [[100, 0], [100, 100], [0, 100], [0, 0]]
```

I want to make it such that if the last element of the list does not equal the first, then it would append the first element as the last, making the list look something like this:

```
List = [[100, 0], [100, 100], [0, 100], [0, 0], [100, 0]]
```

However, when I try to do anything with this list, for example, adding 30 into each element, the first and last elements have the addition done twice, like so:

```
distance = float(input("Please input the distance you want each point to be moved by: "))
direction = float(input("Please input the direction in which you want the polygon to move in: "))
for n in range(len(List)):
    List[n][0] += distance
    List[n][1] += direction
List = [[160.0, 60.0], [130.0, 130.0], [30.0, 130.0], [30.0, 30.0], [160.0, 60.0]]
```

I know this problem is probably because of the append() function, however I don't know why and don't know a workaround, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: `List.append(List[0])` This doesn't append a _copy_ of List[0]; it appends the _actual object_.  So now List[0] and List[-1] are identical references to the same object.

Comment: Many questions about Python lists on StackOverflow revolve around the problem you're having: if you assign a list to another variable in Python, that doesn't create a copy of the list, the variable just has the exact same list as a value. So the list at `List[0]` and `List[-1]` are one and the same list, assigned to two positions of another list. (by the way, it's bad practice to name variables with capitals, it's also generally not a good idea to name a variable after its type - name it after what the contents mean). This isn't caused by `.append()` or anything like that - just Python.

Comment: Ah i see, thanks @Grismar, I'm pretty new to coding, do you know if there's a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

the issue is actually that `List.append(List[0])` doesn't append a copy of the first element, it appends a reference to the first element.

This can be checked using the `id()` function:

```py
# these will be the same location in memory
print(id(List[0]))
print(id(List[-1]))
```

You should use `List.append(List[0].copy())` instead.

This also applies to other mutable datatypes, like dictionaries. Normal assignments produce shallow copies, which are just copies of the reference, not the values.

Comment: Sure. I second the other comment from @Grismar about not naming a variable `List` or `list`. You can pretty easily overwrite actual python stuff by doing that. Instead, try naming variables based on what their values represent. `locations` maybe, for this example.